# Fluent NHibernate bidirectional many to one IConvertible exception

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-one

I'm trying to map a biredictional many-to-one relation between parent/children for the same class/table.
Here is the mapping:

```
References(x => x.Parent).Column("ParentID");
HasMany(x => x.Children).KeyColumn("ParentID").Inverse().Cascade.All();
```

When I try to save a parent with a list of children I get the following error

> System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.

The above mapping works if parent/children are two different classes/tables.
I also tried to make the mapping unidirectional by removing:

```
References(x => x.Parent).Column("ParentID");
```

Then I can save but if I fetch a child the parent is null.

Any ideas how to solve this?

---

Fit.Server.Persistence.Test.Repositories.SagOpgave.SagOpgavePersistenceTest.Opgave_gets_references threw exception:

System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.

```
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType)
at Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlParameter.a(Type A_0)
at Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.q.a(PsqlParameter A_0, k A_1, a3 A_2, Int32 A_3)
at Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.q..ctor(PsqlParameter A_0, k A_1, Int32 A_2, Int32 A_3, Int32 A_4)
at Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlParameterCollection.a(k A_0, Int32 A_1, Int32 A_2, Int32 A_3)
at Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlCommand.a(Boolean A_0, CommandBehavior A_1, Boolean A_2)
at Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
at NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation expectation)
at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute()
at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()
```

Found a solution that works so far.

```
References(x => x.Parent).Column("ParentID").Not.Insert();
HasMany(x => x.Children).KeyColumn("ParentID").Cascade.All();
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for that exception?

Comment: When you posted that stack trace you have been explicitly asked if you want to post an answer to your question and you have been told that you should update your question instead if you want to provide additional info. Those messages are meant to be read. So: Please update your question with the stack trace and delete your non-answer.

Comment: what is the id mapping of the class?

Answer (score 0):

I tried understanding the code and error. Based on that I can see that you have passed some data that is of invalid data type or mismatching with the column data type. Please check all the column values before saving.